# div:active with Opera browser

Tags: css, opera

look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzsTU/). I want that anchor will change its background-color when I click on the parent div. It works only if I click beside anchor. But if I moove cursor on the anchor and then click, nothing happens. It only works fine in firefox and chrome.

```
<div class="test">
  <a href="#">link me</a>
</div>


.test
{
  background:Gray;
}
.test:active a
{
  background:Red;
}
```

Comment: Opera's interpretation seems correct to me.  The focus is on the anchor tag and not its ancestors when you click the link.

Answer (score 1):

For consistency around all browsers i would put the active pseudo on the anchor tag instead.

```
.test a {
  background:Gray;
  display:block;
}
.test a:active {
  background:Red;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzsTU/3/)

Comment: I need change many styles in the parent div by "active" action.

Answer (score 0):

some class and pseudo  not support by **Opera** try in this way, may this solve your problem.

```
.test
{
  background:Gray;
}
.test:active a
{
  background:Red;
}
.test a:active 
{
  background:Red;
}
```